# Remove choice-conflict without look ahead - JavaCC

Tags: java, regex, compiler-construction, javacc

I am trying to make the following production rule in JavaCC but I am getting a choice conflict error. I know how to fix it using look-ahead but I am under the impression we are not allowed to use it for our assignment.

```
void statement() #void:{}
{
  <ID> (<ASSIGN>(expression() | <STRING> ))| <LEFTBRACKET>argument_list()<RIGHTBRACKET>
| <NOT>expression()
| <QUESTIONMARK><ID>
| <LEFTBRACE>(statement()<SEMICOLON>)*<RIGHTBRACE>
| <IF>condition()<THEN>statement()                  <-- Conflict, parser will always pick this one
| <IF>condition()<THEN>statement()<ELSE>statement() <-- 
| <WHILE>condition()<DO>statement()
| {}
}
```

Any thoughts are appreciated !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the classic "dangling else" problem from the [JavaCC lookahead tutorial](http://javacc.java.net/doc/lookahead.html). You should replace the two `if` productions with a single `if-then-else` production that has an optional `else`; you should also add `LOOKAHEAD(1)` in front of the `else`, like this:

```
| <IF>condition()<THEN>statement()
| <IF>condition()<THEN>statement()<ELSE>statement()
```

becomes

```
| <IF>condition()<THEN>statement() [LOOKAHEAD(1) <ELSE>statement()]
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. I did have this solution but I am not sure if we can use lookaheads.. Will the parser still be LL(1) if I use this?

Also, if there is no other solution to this problem then I assume that this is the correct answer! Thanks again

Comment: @Tomcelic I think that adding `LOOKAHEAD(1) <ELSE>` makes it an `LL(2)`, but I'm not 100% certain about it. The grammar remains ambiguous unless you add `<ENDIF>`, but the parser will take it, and pair up the `else` with the innermost `if`.

Comment: Do you think this would work?

/*IF statement*/
void if_statement():{}
{
  <IF>condition()<THEN>statement()(<ELSE>statement() |{})
}

Comment: There is no LL(1) grammar for the classic if-else problem. E.g. there is no LL(1) grammar equivalent to S' -> S $ ; S -> o ; S -> i S ; S -> i S e S.